# Interaction studio doesn't see attribute

Tags: interaction-studio

Trying to update a product catalog with variables stored in datalayer with a code:

```
catalog: {
                Product: {
                    _id: findInDataLayer("id"), // model id
                    sku: findInDataLayer("skuid"), // token
                    name: findInDataLayer("name") , // model name
                    price: findInDataLayer("price"), // total price
```

Even if datalayer loaded correctly, all variables existing (in datalayer, or if logged in console for test purpose) in event stream I see only null values. Why it might happen?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while so I guess you already figured out but let me suggest a tip. Try to check Settings > Catalog and Profile Objects > Security. If `Enable Strict Catalog Security` is checked, catalog data won't be updated via SDK. If so, try to turn off and reload the page again.